# Method to execute query with ? parameter

Tags: java

I want to generalize a method executeQuery.
Now I have in a DbUtils class:

```
public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD);
    return connection;
}

public static <T> List<T> executeQuery(String sql, RowMapper<T> rowMapper){
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();

    try (Connection connection = DbUtils.getConnection()) {
        try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            try (ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery()) {
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    T row = rowMapper.mapRow(resultSet);
                    result.add(row);
                }
                result.forEach(System.out::println);
                return result;
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

In my testFile I call the connectionTest method :

```
public void connectionTest() {

    DbUtils.executeQuery("select id,description,quantity from products", resultSet -> {
        try {
            Prodotto prodotto = new Prodotto();

            prodotto.setId(resultSet.getString("id"));
            prodotto.setDescription(resultSet.getString("description"));
            prodotto.setQuantity(resultSet.getInt("quantity"));

            return prodotto;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

Now it works fine but if I want to do a query like this:

```
"select id,description,quantity from products where id>?"
```

or

```
"select id,description,quantity from products where id>? and description=? "
```

How can I edit the executeQuery method in the DbUtils class?
Sure I need to pass another property in the executeQuery method but it can be String or Integer or something else.. and this property must be a map because the user could pass a query in which there are more ? so I need to manage it.

In the executeQuery method I'll add :

```
public static <T> List<T> executeQuery(String sql, RowMapper<T> rowMapper,Map<String,V> newPropertyPassedInExecuteQueryMethod){
List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();

try (Connection connection = DbUtils.getConnection()) {
    try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        newPropertyPassedInExecuteQueryMethod.forEach((key,value)-> 
            preparedStatement.setIntOrStringOrSomethingElse(key,value);
        )
        try (ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery()) {
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                T row = rowMapper.mapRow(resultSet);
                result.add(row);
            }
            result.forEach(System.out::println);
            return result;
        }
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

}

How can I do it ?

Comment: `preparedStatement.setString(1, description)` for example.

Comment: You can do it with an `Object... args`, simply setting these args by index for the parameters within the query. This would also enable you to use indexed parameters in the query itself to avoid duplicate arguments.

Comment: @Rogue Could you write your solution?

Comment: I can link you a [similar piece of code](https://github.com/Codelanx/CodelanxCommons/blob/master/src/main/java/com/codelanx/commons/data/SQLDataType.java#L68-L102) I made myself years ago. The only thing I'd improve in that method now is probably adding some non-blocking IO for it (e.g. using `CompletableFuture`). The rest of the class needs a little TLC here and there as well for considering multi-threading, though.